# How do I create a dialog box that opens a website within itself while staying on my SharePoint site in the background?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sharepoint, modal-dialog

I have been working with SharePoint Online and I have been doing some research into this issue but I just can't figure it out so I am thinking about recreating a certain part of my SP site from scratch.

I am creating a table of stuff and putting the links to reference material on the side but I needed to create a dialog box or iFrame that shows the website of the reference material inside the box while staying on the same SP site in the background. 
Kind of like this --> http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup-iframe/

This demo has a video and map that load up but I wanted an entire website to load inside the box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}
/* Spacer for template*/
td.spacer   {
                margin-left: 100px
            }
/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'Tab1')">Tab1</button>
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'Tab2')">Tab2</button>
 </div>

<div id="Systems Design" class="tabcontent">
<table style="width:50%">  
    <th> Description </th>
    <th> Link </th>
        <tr>
            <td>Desc1</td>          
            <td style="width:25%"> <a href = "https://www.google.com">Click 
Here</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Desc2 </td>
            <td> <a href = "https://www.google.com">Click Here</a></td>
        </tr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframes can be finicky. Many websites will only allow same origins requests, meaning the iframe wont render as a resource on a domain that isn't its own. Additionally, the security must match ie, an `http` site cannot load an `https` iframe. A workaround could be to use an `img` tag and a screenshot of the site in the popup.

Comment: Is there any way to make a a dialog box come up to show the functional website?

Comment: you could open a new browser window to be a smaller size and look like a dialog box, like `window.open('https://google.com', 'windowName', 'top=50, width=700, left=100, height=500')`